# Using tiled maps for a soccer field in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am writing a simple soccer game in cocos2d-x and recently found out that older iOS versions do not support cocos2d sprites larger than 1024x1024px.

I was thinking about using isometric tilemaps to create a larger football field.

Is this the way to go ? If so, how can i convert a  convert my 2048x2048px football field image into several isometric tiles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use a TMX tile map, it is far more efficient and smoother than using a huge sprite anyway and consumes far less memory. Have a look for a tilemap program such as 'Tiled'.

For the football pitch just draw a few grass tiles and some with line markings on them, then you 'paint' these tiles onto your tilemap. It depends on how you want it to look, but you should only need to draw just a few tiles (the performance advantage comes from using the same tiles many times).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at this tutorial by Ray Wenderlich:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d

It covers a little more than you may need, but does show step by step the process to both create a tile map and get it on the iPhone using Cocos2d. Tiled is really the way to go as it plays nicely with Cocos2d.

I would have to see a picture of the football field to give you good advice on how to convert it into several isometric tiles, but if you're just looking for a program GIMP is great and can be found here:

http://www.gimp.org/